# Close list with variables with the fixed number -1

Tags: java

I am very new to coding and Java. I have the following assignment: Write a program that reads a couple of positive numbers from the input and computes and prints the average, with 3 decimals precision. The input list closes with the number -1.

So I have a working program, however I have no clue how to integrate the condition 'print the average with 3 decimals precision'. Do you have any idea how to fix this? Many thanks!

See my code below:

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Parta {

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    Scanner numInput = new Scanner(System.in);

    double avg = 0.0;
    double count = 0.0;
    double sum = 0.0;

    System.out.println("Enter a series of numbers. Enter -1 to quit.");

    while (numInput.hasNextDouble())
    {
        double negNum = numInput.nextDouble();
        if (negNum == -1)
        {
            System.out.println("You entered " + count + " numbers averaging " + avg + ".");
            break;
        }
        else
        {
            sum += negNum;
            count++;
            avg = sum/count;
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: The `int` data type can not store any precision. You can use `double` for that. Your loop is almost correct, but `numbers.length + 1 = -1` translates to `-1`. A single `=` denotes an assignment, while `==` is equality check. I would change your loop to the following: `for (int i = 0; i < numbers.length - 1; i++) {`. That way, it'll keep asking the user for input until the second to last index of the array. You can then use `numbers[numbers.length - 1] = -1` to set the last value to -1.

Comment: Add an if statement to check if n == -1 and break the for loop if it is.

Comment: Or translate for loop to do/while with condition n != -1

Answer (score 0):

You just have to break out of the loop for your -1 condition.

```
while(1) {

Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
 int n = sc.nextInt();
  if(n == -1)
   break;
  }
```

Comment: Thank you! I changed my code set-up and it's working. Now I only need to adjust the 3 decimal accuracy requirement. Any ideas how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
for(int i=0; i < numbers.length + 1= -1 ; i++)
```

to

```
for(int i=0; i < n ; i++)
```

The

```
%n
```

is out of place in the print statement also. I'd remove that.

To implement your -1 condition, check for a == -1 in the for loop:

```
if (a == -1) {break;}
```

Comment: Thank you! I changed my code set-up and it's working. Now I only need to adjust the 3 decimal accuracy requirement. Any ideas how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

> The input list closes with the number -1.

I assume this means that -1 is the final number you are looking for and when read then all inputs are then completed? You just need a condition to check if the number you are looking at is -1, if it is then stop reading.

Comment: Thank you! I changed my code set-up and it's working. Now I only need to adjust the 3 decimal accuracy requirement. Any ideas how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Your code does not meet your requirements.

The first requirement is that you have to calculate *fractions*. But you stick to `int` as type of your variables. As written by @nbokmans your variables should be of type `double` or `float`.

The other problem is that your code takes the first number given as the count of the numbers to follow. But you're told to use any number for calculation until input is `-1`. You cannot do this with a `for` loop, you  need a `while` loop for this.

An the easiest way to accomplish your task is to calculate the result *on the fly* while getting the input:

pseudo code:

```
declare sum as double initially 0.0;
while(input is not -1)
  sum = (sum + input) / 2;

output sum:
```